# How can I fill the bottom of 3d plots in Mathematica?

Tags: plotting, filling

I am working with a graph where all of its bottom should be filled, I applied certain filling styles, however, that did not work. Could any body please assist in this case. [image: XX with respect to t]

The code I applied is:

```
Plot3D[XYZ /. {α -> 3, g -> 0.01},
 {p, 0, 1}, {τ, 0, 10},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 Mesh -> 12,
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 21, FontWeight -> "Bold"},
 AxesLabel -> {p, t},
 ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Darker[Orange], Darker[Green]}, #3] &),
 PlotRange -> {1, 0},
 BoxRatios -> {0.7, 1, 0.6},
 Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {0, 0.5, 1}},
 TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20],
 AxesStyle -> Thick,
 PlotLabel -> Style[XX, 21],
 FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}]
```

Where

```
XYZ = ((-1 + Abs[p]/2 + (1/4) E^Re[-8 τ - (8*(1 + g*τ)^(2 - α))/(g*(-2 + α))] 
    Abs[(E^(8/(g (-2 + α))) + E^(8*τ + (8*(1 + g*τ)^(2 - α))/(g*(-2 + α)))) p]
    + (1/4) Abs[p - E^(8/(g (-2 + α)) - 8 τ - (8*(1 + g*τ)^(2 - α))
    /(g*(-2 + α))) p] + (E^((1/2) Re[-16 τ - (16 (1 + g*τ)^(2 - α))
    /(g*(-2 + α))]) Sqrt[Abs[(-E^(16/(g (-2 + α)))) p^2 - 
    E^(16 τ + (16*(1 + g*τ)^(2 - α))/(g*(-2 + α)))*p^2]])
    /Sqrt[2])^3)^1.5
```

Comment: Show the code that you used, including any data and code for a minimal working example.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Following is the code, I am working on. Plot3D[ABCD /. {\[Alpha] -> 3, g -> 0.01}, {p, 0, 1}, {\[Tau], 0, 10}, Filling -> Bottom, Mesh -> 12, BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 21, FontWeight -> "Bold"}, AxesLabel -> {p, t}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[{Darker[Orange], Darker[Green]}, #3] & ), PlotRange -> {1, 0}, BoxRatios -> {0.7, 1, 0.6}, Ticks -> {{0, 0.5, 1}, {0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10}, {0, 0.5, 1}}, 
  TicksStyle -> Directive[Black, 20], AxesStyle -> Thick, PlotLabel -> Style[XX, 21], FaceGrids -> {{0, -1, 0}, {-1, 0, 0}}]

Comment: I will add the code to your question. However, you also need edit your question to include the definition of `ABCD` to have a working example.

Comment: The code works fine (fills to bottom) if I replace `XYZ` by `p`.  Voting to close until code that reproduces the problem is posted.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Bob and Michael. I regenerated the question with the equation, I am plotting.  Could you please reconsider viewing it. As, I am still stuck at it

Comment: I corrected the format of `XYZ` which could not be run as written.  However, I am reasonably confident that your expression for `XYZ` is incorrect.  Please check.

Comment: Thanks, I will check for that @bbgodfrey

Comment: Your code works ok unless $g$ is less than about $1/80$ at which point I obtain a max precision limit error:  `N::meprec: Internal precision limit $MaxExtraPrecision = 200. reached while evaluating E^720.`